# How do i find the address of the treasury?

Tags: substrate-node-template, kusama, substrate-parachain-template

I have implemented `pallet_treasury` just like Kusama, how do i find the resulting address?

Comment: See also: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/536/how-do-treasury-accounts-compare-to-end-user-accounts-in-frame/541#541

Answer (score 4):

Find the pallet id in runtime first. Different networks might use different id. [Kusama treasury pallet id](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L636)

Use [subalfred](https://github.com/hack-ink/subalfred).

```
λ subalfred key 'py/trsry' --key-type pallet --network kusama
public-key 0x6d6f646c70792f74727372790000000000000000000000000000000000000000 PalletId(py/trsry)
kusama F3opxRbN5ZbjJNU511Kj2TLuzFcDq9BGduA9TgiECafpg29
```

https://kusama.subscan.io/account/F3opxRbN5ZbjJNU511Kj2TLuzFcDq9BGduA9TgiECafpg29

Comment: Can I use this tool for a custom Substrate chain?

Comment: Sure. It use the same algorithm as substrate. —network just change the ss58 prefix. public key is the same.

Answer (score 4):

```js
import { stringToU8a } from '@polkadot/util';
import { encodeAddress } from '@polkadot/util-crypto';

const treasuryAddress = encodeAddress(stringToU8a("modlpy/trsry".padEnd(32, '\0')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another using just `subkey`:

```bash
$ HEX=$(printf "modlpy/trsry" | xxd -p)
$ PUBLIC_KEY=$(printf 0x%-64s $HEX | tr " " 0)
$ subkey inspect $PUBLIC_KEY --network kusama --public
Network ID/Version: kusama
  Public key (hex):   0x6d6f646c70792f74727372790000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  Account ID:         0x6d6f646c70792f74727372790000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  Public key (SS58):  F3opxRbN5ZbjJNU511Kj2TLuzFcDq9BGduA9TgiECafpg29
  SS58 Address:       F3opxRbN5ZbjJNU511Kj2TLuzFcDq9BGduA9TgiECafpg29
```