# How to read treasury pallet funds?

Tags: substrate-node-template, balances, pallet-treasury

I am able to add funds in treasury pallet, now I want to get the total balance of treasury pool. How can this be done? Can someone provide some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this link for information on how to find the accounts used behind the treasury pallet: [How to find the accounts used behind treasury pallet?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7033/how-to-find-the-accounts-used-behind-treasury-pallet).

Consider this address as a normal account, with its free balance representing the treasury funds.